# libuv vs. glib gio: Which is a better option?

Tags: glib, libuv

I am looking for a C library for asynchronous I/O, TCP/UDP networking support, threads and event loops. 
I looked at GLib's GIO, GThread, GMainContext, GMainLoop and also Libuv which is used by Node.js.  The functionality is similar. THere seems to be no comparison on these two libraries. I am looking for pure C support on Linux only. I do not care for portability or multiple-language support.

Any suggestions or pointers as to which is relatively easy to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLib/GIO provides more other functionality than libuv, although from the list you’ve provided it looks like like libuv does provide everything you want.

GObject (which GIO is based on) has a set of conventions which take a bit of time to get up to speed on (though there are documentation and tutorials available); once you’re up to speed on them, they make writing object-oriented code in C fairly painless.

I haven’t used libuv, so can’t speak for it.

Comment: I am aware of your observation but among other things, Glib does not use epoll but I concur otherwise.

Comment: Amazing that there is no comparison anywhere on the net even though there is so much similarity in the two libraries for the purpose I am seeking.

Comment: Correct, GLib does not currently use epoll(). There is a bug open about it (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699132), but it’s unlikely to be fixed in the immediate future.

Comment: There is also a [branch in the GLib repository](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/commit/f8e2ac9319c7b9024888a63a4fa945a750811732) with an epoll implementation

Comment: That branch is 4 years old, unfinished and unmaintained. (As a GLib maintainer) I advise people not to use it.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall Any opinion on glib's support for dtls with srtp? That is what  my end goal is... to write a rtp/rtcp server for use with webRtc. Long way to go but want to make the right decisions at the start...  I mean compared to openssl or boringssl, both of which also support dtls with srtp (C API).

Comment: It should be sufficient. I’ve written a similar ICE-based server/client using GLib/GIO and libnice, and it used GLib’s DTLS support. GStreamer has also recently introduced a WebRTC plugin (although I suspect it’s just a client), which probably uses the same code. See here: https://github.com/centricular/gstwebrtc-demos